# Getting error Cannot find module 'rxjs/operators' while trying "import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators'"

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, node-modules

In my angular 2 application I was trying to import - `import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators'`. But it resulted in an error **TS2307   (TS) Cannot find module 'rxjs/operators'** and because of that I am not able to use **tap** and **catchError** error operators using observable.

When I checked my local folder **operators** folder was not there in **node_modules/rxjs** folder. Instead I had only **operator** which unfortunately does not have the operators **tap** and **catchError**. please find below my folder screens [image]. Please somebody help me.

[image]

Comment: I guess you are using an older version of rxjs. Can you share the version of Angular and rxjs from package.json file?

Comment: You seem to be using RxJS <= 5.4. You should be able to use `do` instead of `tap` and `catch` instead of `catchError`.

Comment: @Shravan in package.jason "@angular/common" and "@angular/compiler"..etc is given as "~4.3.4" and "rxjs": "5.0.1".  If it is because RxJs lower version,,how do I install higher version of RxJs so that i can use  **tap** and **cathcError**

Comment: @fridoo I have to use **tap** and **catchError** at any cost no alternate will help me

Comment: You have to update the Angular version as it will automatically update rxjs as well. You cannot independently update rxjs as every Angular version is dependent on a specific version of rxjs. Angular 5 is not supported by Google and it will not receive any patches. Update to Angular 9 which is the largest LTS version.